# Alfresco - Configure 2 groupSearchBases for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, alfresco

How to configure 2 groupSearchBases for Alfresco?

Right now i have this property in my global.properties:

```
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=CN\=Alfresco users,OU\=Users,OU\=AWE,DC\=main,DC\=awe
```

But i need to configure second search base with path

> CN=Alfresco users,OU=Labs,OU=AWE,DC=main,DC=awe

. What i have tried is to configure the property with ***OR*** statement like this:

```
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=(|(CN\=Alfresco users,OU\=Users,OU\=AWE,DC\=main,DC\=awe)(CN\=Alfresco users,OU\=Labs,OU\=AWE,DC\=main,DC\=awe))
```

This setting gave me an error:

```
00:30:07,147 ERROR [org.alfresco.repo.security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] Synchronization aborted due to error
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02290000 Error during LDAP Search. Reason: null
...
Caused by: javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out, timeout used:5000ms. [Root exception is com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralException: Continuation Reference; remaining name 'DC\=main,DC\=awe']; remaining name '']
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: LDAP response read timed out, timeout used:5000ms. [Root exception is com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralException: Continuation Reference; remaining name 'DC\=main,DC\=awe']; remaining name ''
...
Caused by: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapReferralException: Continuation Reference; remaining name 'DC\=main,DC\=awe'
```

I also minimized the searchBase path to include both of the directories like this:

```
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=CN\=Alfresco users,OU\=AWE,DC\=main,DC\=awe
```

But this also gave me an error:

```
    org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 02310000 Error during LDAP Search. Reason: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: 'OU=AWE,DC=main,DC=awe'
...
    Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:'OU=AWE,DC=main,DC=awe'
```

What i am doing wrong and how to make alfresco search for both groupSearchBases (the easiest way if possible). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What LDAP server are you talking to? (The right syntax varies)

Comment: Active directory. I didnt know that this i important. @Gagravarr

Comment: You can only set one group base. You can use `OU=AWE,DC=main,DC=awe` (which contains both OU=Labs  and OU=Users) and then try to filter them via the groupQuery, eg. `(&(objectclass=group)(|(OU=Labs)(OU=Users))(CN=Alfresco users))`, this should work if the group entries refers to their respective OU's. Otherwise (if the goal is to sync members of these groups), you can also add filters to the personQuery, eg. `(&(objectclass=user)(memberOf:...))`.

Comment: You can only have the one search base, as @EricLavault explained you need to do the filtering on the query. However, only some LDAP servers support filtering based on the tree the entry lives in. IIRC with AD it's something like `ou:dn:=labs` to get an OU within the DN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, the search base is a LDAP (Distinguished Name) path, not a query. This means that you should select the search base for your user and group query to a path for which both organizational units are subordinate: `OU=AWE,DC=main,DC=awe`.

Then you need to build the users and groups *query* so that only groups and users are returned as expected. E.g. for the person query can look like this:

```
(&
 (objectCategory\=Person)
 (|
   (memberOf\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941\:\=CN\=Alfresco users,OU\=Users,OU\=AWE,DC\=main,DC\=awe)
   (memberOf\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941\:\=CN\=Alfresco users,OU\=Labs,OU\=AWE,DC\=main,DC\=awe)
 )
 (userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512)
)
```

for the group search you should do the same.

hint: `1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` is a Active-Directory specific filter to retrieve nested groups (recursive retrieval of all members of that DN). For more info check [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters | MS Tecnet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)